# Kamailo - number of open files

Tags: bash, kamailio

is there any possibility to track number of open files, which are used while Kamailio handle new calls? So far, I tried to use script in bash and start the script using `watch` command

```
FILES=$(ls -l '/proc/'$(pidof kamailio)'/fd' | wc -l)
echo $FILES >> FILES.txt
```

I got this kind of result:

```
ls: cannot access '1809' : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '1808' : No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '1807' : No such file or directory
.
.
.
ls: cannot access '1795/fd' : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Show output of `pidof kamailio`.

Comment: Seems like `pidof` returns multiple PIDs. Either loop over them or pick only one using `pidof -s`.

Comment: At this moment output of `pidof kamailio` is: 1813 1808 1807 1806 1805 1804 1803 1802 1801 1800 1799 1798 1797 1795

Answer (score 0):

Since kamailio in most systems running under kamailio user, you can do something like this:

```
lsof -u kamailio | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks for help. The command works and I don´t get error message anymore, but when I have increasing number of simultaneous call, result of command is still same

Comment: Why you think increase number of calls increase files handles? It increase sockets. See netstat -a

Comment: A socket is a file handle. The question is why a new call should consume a file handle/socket. Hint: it doesn't have to.

Comment: Thats how sockets originized in linux/unix, sorry.